# How to declare a generic method with a generic collection?

Tags: c#, generics, generic-collections

For example

```
void f<C, T>(C<T> collection, T element) : where C has member method BindarySearch
```

I have two questions:

1. If it is possible to declare a generic method with a generic collection? If so, how?
2. How to make C has a particular member method?
   Thanks.

Comment: (1) If you mean whether or not you can use a Generic Collection Type as a type argument (i.e `List<T>`) then the answer is yes you can. (2) You need to declare an interface (containing the member you want to enforce) and specify a conversion type constraint on C (i.e `where C : IContract`)

Answer (score 1):

You can use an interface to enforce the required members:

```
interface IHasBinarySearch<T> : ICollection<T> {
    int BinarySearch(T item);
}
```

Then a generic method can be defined like so:

```
void f<C, T>(C collection, T element) where C : IHasBinarySearch<T>
```

This interface is already a generic collection (by extending `ICollection<T>`) so no need to specify the constraint on the method again.